# Are there any alternatives to the Apple Mighty Mouse that have the small trackball for scrolling?

Tags: mouse, hardware-rec, product-rec, trackball

Other than the Mighty Mouse itself, that is, as I don't like their tactile "feel". Preferably with:

- USB interface
- OSX/Windows support
- 3+ buttons

Comment: Do you mean the physical behavior? Or the single-button deal, the button actions are configurable...

Comment: I figured he wanted something that has the trackball "scroll wheel", which I cannot find anything yet.

Comment: @Troggy: Correct. I don't like the feel of the Mighty Mouse, but I do like the trackball "scroll wheel", so I'm looking for another alternative that's got one of these on it.

Comment: I'm on the same boat. Particularly, I don't like that the mighty mouse tends to break. I'd also expect 4 mouse buttons, at least. (Mighty Mouse has left, right, on wheel, and pressure thing on the sides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [Targus Laser Mouse](http://www.targus.com/us/product_details.asp?sku=AMB08US) or [Targus Wireless Mouse](http://www.targus.com/us/product_details.asp?sku=AMW43US)

Both use a wireless USB connection, and have the standard two buttons plus two programmable buttons on the side.

They are designed for Mac, but I've never had a mouse that won't work on Windows as well...

Comment: Ooh, looks nice -- I'll investigate Windows compatibility.

Comment: Also: I guess that's not technically a scrollball on the mouse, but looks like a similar concept.

Comment: Specifications do indicate Windows support.

Answer (score 3):

The small trackball on the Mighty Mouse is commonly referred to as a "scroll ball."

Genius - the first manufacturer to put a scroll wheel on a mouse - makes several corded USB mice which have scroll balls, three or more buttons and support for both Windows and Mac OS.

Some of the mice from the [Genius product line](http://geniusnet.com) which I anticipate will meet your requirements are the Ergo T555, Traveler 515, Navigator 525, Traveler 525 and the NetScroll T220.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a wired version but: [Kensington SlimBlade](http://us.kensington.com/html/14488.html)

Comment: +1 for the trackball -- only two buttons though. :( I'll update the question to mention button count.